# Redis Connection Error in Python

Tags: python, redis

I am using Redis version 3.0.3 on Ubuntu. I have changed the maxclients in my redis.conf to 1000000 (10Lakhs). I have also enabled connection pooling in my code. ulimit -n is 99999. Inspite of that I am getting the redis.ConnectionError in python when I try to create multiple threads for pub/sub operations. What can be done to handle this scenario? How to avoid this exception? Thanks in advance for your appreciable responses.

Comment: Do you get a traceback or error message? If so, could you add it to your question?

Comment: Am getting a traceback.